# Display div affected by CSS3 animation on top

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a div card that plays an animation on click, which includes the card scaling to be larger. The problem is that as the card scales bigger, it's edges are displayed under other cards. http://puu.sh/oqtEs/5c0d525f8d.png

I was able to fix this by adding z-index to the class that gets applied on click, but it did not work on Safari, but did work on Chrome, FireFox and Edge.

```
@-webkit-keyframes flipAndZoomAnim
{
   0%   { -webkit-transform: rotateY(0deg) scale(0.5) translateZ(1px) }
   20%  { -webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg) scale(0.5) translateZ(1px) }
   40%  { -webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg) scale(1.0) translateZ(1px) }
   80%  { -webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg) scale(1.0) translateZ(1px) }
   100% { -webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg) scale(0.5 ) translateZ(1px) }
}

@keyframes flipAndZoomAnim
{
   0%   { transform: rotateY(0deg) scale(0.5) translateZ(1px) }
   20%  { transform: rotateY(180deg) scale(0.5) translateZ(1px) }
   40%  { transform: rotateY(180deg) scale(1.0) translateZ(1px) }
   80%  { transform: rotateY(180deg) scale(1.0) translateZ(1px) }
   100% { transform: rotateY(180deg) scale(0.5) translateZ(1px) }
}

.flipAndZoom {
    z-index: 5;
    webkit-transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
    transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
    -webkit-animation-name: flipAndZoomAnim;
    animation-name: flipAndZoomAnim;
}
```

There is some solutions on how to do this online, but I found none with animations. Including the `translateZ(1px)`, was suggested but did not work, as well as `translate3d(0,0,0);`

HTML

```
<div id="board">
     <div id="card1" class="card">
          <figure class="front">
               <img src="front.jpg"/>
          </figure>
          <figure class="back">
               <img src="back.jpg"/>      
          </figure>
     </div>

     <div id="card2" class="card">
          <figure class="front">
              <img src="front.jpg"/>
          </figure>
          <figure class="back">
              <img src="back.jpg"/>      
          </figure>
     </div>
</div>
```

I have the cards displayed row by row in a div, to which they are added by JavaScript.

```
   for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
        $('#board').append(card.getHTML());
    }
```

What I find interesting that the zoomed in card is systematically displayed under the other cards, but never over.

Here is the website: http://valtterilaine.bitbucket.org/public_html/

Comment: Could you put up a fiddle?

Comment: The translateZ(1px) would work usually moving the div towards the user . But if you rotate the div 180deg, it will move it backwards...  Have you tried changing it to -1px ?

Comment: If you can't put it in a fiddle or snippet at least put it on [plunker](http://plnkr.co/).

Comment: Here is the entire website: http://valtterilaine.bitbucket.org/public_html/

Comment: Im working on the fiddle...

Comment: for some reason it works on the fiddle, but not on the website. https://jsfiddle.net/aLq9sv79/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Changing

```
translateZ(1px)
```

to

```
translateZ(-1px)
```

fixed the issue. Since the cards are flipped they were being translated backwards.

Comment: If Vals wants to post an answer, I'll delete this and grant bounty to him.

Answer (score 0):

Z-index should do its job, howerver may be missing the position rule.

In order to make z-index work, you must set either on of following values for position: absolute, relative or fixed. In this case the

```
position: relative;
```

is desired, I suppose.